# Bayesian Network

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I am new to machine learning.

I have a BN with 4 variables [X1,X2,X3,X4] and I am interested in predicting Y based on those. For the training data I have [X1,X2,X3,X4,Y]. But for actual data I have only [X1,X2,X3] and I want to predict Y. Additionally I know that X4 is conditionally independent from X1,X2 and X3.

Is this possible? Is there a standard technique to do this?

Comment: $P(Y|X1,X2,X3) = \int P(Y|X1,X2,X3,X4)P(X4) dX4$

Comment: Thx got the idea. However still thinking of a way to do it. For example I have a data file of [t,X1,X2,X2,X4,Y] for training and another for [t,X1,X2,X3] for which I need to predict [t is the timestamp]. For the latter I can not just calculate P(X4) can I?

Comment: X4 is conditionally independent of (X1,X2,X3) given *what*?

Comment: P(X4/X1)=P(X4) and so on...

Comment: Can you provide sample codes that produce CPT from data? I have the same problem. I want to train a BN from data dataframe(t, X1,X2,X3,...X8,Y) and then predict Y or its probability for new coming data datarow(t1, X1,X2,X3,...X8). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a time-stamp, i.e. the data is temporal and not i.i.d., you should use one of these:

**i.** a Markov Chain;

**ii**. a Hidden Markov Model;

**iii.** a Dynamic Bayesian Networks.

Note that the complexity (and the sophistication) of the solution increases from i. to iii.

Hope this helps.